# Execute HTTP requests in by-pass order

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, http, request

What I would like to achieve is to execute synchronously an ordered sequence of HTTP requests, but depending on the value of some variables, I want some of them to be by-passed.

As an example (I am using the `request` library in Javascript to do so):

```
request(httpReq1, function(error, response, body) {
  // do something, like handling errors...
  request(httpReq2, function(error, response, body) {
    // do something else
  });
});
```

So this ensures that `httpReq2` will execute after `httpReq1`.

What I am not sure is how to by-pass the first request if, for example, some flag is set to false, and instead of executing `httpReq1` and wait for a response, it just jumps to `httpReq2`, **keeping the order**:

```
if (dontMakeHttpReq1) // where should this be placed?

request(httpReq1, function(error, response, body) {
  // do something, like handling errors...
  request(httpReq2, function(error, response, body) {
    // do something else
  });
});
```

What would be a good approach to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sort out a list of requests needed in an array, and execute them sequentially using the `async/await`

```
let requests = [];
if (doRequest1)
  requests.push(httpReq1);

if (doRequest2)
  requests.push(httpReq2);

/* etc .. for httpReq3 and so on */

// now execute them one by one in sequence
for(let req of requests) {
   try {
     await request(req);
   } catch (err) {
     // error handling here
   }
}
```

Comment: Definitely, this is the way to go!

Answer (score 1):

You can use async-await to achieve that.

```
async apiCall(){ 
    try{
     if(condition){
      const result1 = await request(httpReq1);
     }
     const result2 = await request(httpReq2);
    }
    catch(error){

    }
}
```

make sure that request module retruns a promise. Otherwise create a promise wrapper. [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) is a library that is promise based.

You have to put async before the function that includes your awaits

Comment: Hey, looks good. The problem is that I just want to skip the first (ideally, any request in the main chain) request depending on the status of some variable: you are always making the first request.

Comment: Check the edit. Just consider await calls as synchronized statements. They execute in order and waits until callback is called

Comment: No problem. Was just curious.

Answer (score 1):

Why not using 2 conditions?

```
if (dontMakeHttpReq1) {
  request(req1, function(error, response, body) {
    yourRequestProcessing2();
  });
}
else {
  request(req1, function(error, response, body) {
    request(req2, function(error, response, body) {
      yourRequestProcessing2();
    });
    yourRequestProcessing1();
  });
}
```

Edit: Maybe you want to store the request calls in arrays

```
//Whether request n should skip
var flags = [
  false,
  true,
  false
];
var requests = [
  function(error, response, body) {
    //Process your request 1
  },
  function(error, response, body) {
    //Process your request 2
  },
  function(error, response, body) {
    //Process request 3
  }
];
for (i = 0; i < requests.length; i++) {
  if (flags[i]) {
    request(req1, requests[i + 1]);
  }
  else {
    request(req2, request[i]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. I don't like that approach because I have a chain of multiple requests. So I'm trying to avoid repeating code.

Comment: Are the request all based on their previous? There are no jumps like from request 3 to request 2?

Comment: They should be executed in order and always maintaining the number of requests in the chain.